# Next row in gridview asp.net jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, aspxgridview

I am using ASP.NET to create a page with a GridView and Image , this code show in Image GridView's first row picture, how can I get next row source?

```
$('#Image1').src = $('#grdImages td img').src;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also this syntax is wrong as a `jQuery` object has no method called `src` .. A `DOM` object does..

Try this instead

`$('#grdImages td img')[0].src;` // Plain javascript

`$('#grdImages td img').attr('src');` // jQuery

If you are in the context of an event try this

```
$(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find('img').attr('src')
```

You can always select the row using `eq` selector

```
$('#grdImages).find('tr:eq(1) img').attr('src');
```

Selects the second row.

Comment: $('#Image1').src=$('#grdImages').find('tr:eq(1) img').attr('src');
TypeError: Object #<HTMLTableElement> has no method 'find'

Comment: oops... Try this selector instead `$('[id*=grdImages]')` .. You are using `ASp.NET` server controls right..

Comment: Try `console.log($('[id*=grdImages]').length)`  and check if it is giving a length of 1 .. Also make sure you enclose you code inside `$(function() {  // your code  });`

Comment: Error: SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12. im using jquery first time. and i dont know where is mistake